# Aggregating object values of JavaScript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

In JavaScript, given n number of arrays as input in this format: (n=2)

```
array1:
[{x: 1, y: 5},{x: 2, y: 3},{x: 3, y: 6}]

array2:
[{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 2, y: 6},{x: 3, y: 2}]
```

How do I aggregate the Y-values easily and get this resulting array:

```
arrayOutput:
[{x: 1, y: 7},{x: 2, y: 9},{x: 3, y: 8}]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you give us more information about the values? For instance, in your example, each array's entries have unique `x` values (e.g., the same `x` doesn't appear in the same array). Is that guaranteed? Is `x` the deciding factor for whether you combine `y` values, or is it the position in the array? Things like that.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: You can assume that all arrays have the same length with same unique x-values in same order. The number of arrays will though be very large so an efficient function would be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, okay, that changes things.

Comment: Incase you up for jquery, you should check jquery extend.http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Comment: @Neeraj jQuery and `.extend` are not the right tools here. ES5 shim & `underscore` are the right tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The additional comment about the `x` values and their positions in the arrays makes the below irrelevant.

There's no particular trick, you just loop through the arrays and build up your result. It's nothing more than a nested loop. If you're trying to be maximally efficient across a broad range of JavaScript engines, avoid unnecessary function calls.

*Something* along the lines of:

```
function sumYValues(arrays) {
    var outer, inner, array, entry, sum, result, x;

    // Create our result array with a copy of the first array
    result = [];
    if (arrays.length > 0) {
        array = arrays[0];
        for (inner = 0; inner < array.length; ++inner) {
            entry = array[inner];
            result[inner] = {x: entry.x, y: entry.y};
        }

        // Add in the remaining values
        for (outer = 1; outer < arrays.length; ++outer) {
            array = arrays[outer];
            // You might want an assert here verifying that result.length == array.length
            for (inner = 0; inner < array.length; ++inner) {
                entry = array[inner];
                // You might want an assert here verifying that result[inner].x == entry.x
                result[inner].y += entry.y;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Those loops count from `0` (or `1`) to `array.length - 1`. You might profile whether going backwards (`array.length - 1` to `0` (or 1)) is any faster, mostly the "down to `0`" one. I used to assume it was because it was in C when I was a fresh-faced youth (comparisons to `0` are faster than comparisons to another variable), but that assumption may or may not be valid in JavaScript.

---

There's no particular shortcut, you just loop through the arrays, do your comparisons, and build up your result.

If the `x` values will be unique in each array, it may be easier to keep track of your ongoing sum by using an object rather than an array and using `x` values as keys, and then converting it into an array when you're done. E.g.:

```
function sumYValues(arrays) {
    var outer, inner, ar, entry, sum, result, x;

    sum = {};
    for (outer = 0; outer < arrays.length; ++outer) {
        ar = arrays[outer];
        for (inner = 0; inner < arrays.length; ++inner) {
            entry = ar[inner];
            sum[entry.x] = (sum[entry.x] || 0) + entry.y;
        }
    }

    result = [];
    for (x in sum) {
        result.push({x: x, y: sum[x]});
    }

    return result;
}
```

The above is mostly just to demonstrate using `sum`, an object, as a map of `x` => `y` values, although it does implement at least some of the summing logic as well.

This line may need some explanation:

```
            sum[entry.x] = (sum[entry.x] || 0) + entry.y;
```

If `sum` doesn't have an entry for that `x` value, `sum[entry.x]` will be `undefined`, which is a "falsey" value. So we use the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) to either get the value for that `x` from `sum` *or* `0`, and then add the current entry's `y` to it and store the result.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll check the profiling aspects as well.

Comment: J.Crowder [Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/underscore-vs-manual/3). `inner < arrays.length` should be `inner < ar.length`. My implementation is faster on chrome ;) you _underestimate_ the JIT.

Comment: @TJCrowder yes it's become noise. (cleaned it up) @dani in terms of optimisation, native methods create new objects. If you want a new array (like the array your returning) use the native methods. If you don't need a new object then use for/while loops to edit the array in memory.

Answer (score 3):

[Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/underscore-vs-manual/8)
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mwKaX/3/)

Note that the mixed code is faster followed by loops followed by native/underscore.

```
function createOutput(arr1, arr2, arr3 /*, ... */) {
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (prev, curr) {
        return prev.map(function(val, index) {
            return {
                x: val.x,
                y: val.y + curr[index].y
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Assumes arrays are sorted and contain all values of `x` in order 1..n with no gaps.

Kind of requires ES5. This can be swapped out for [`_`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) which gives this kind of functionality in a cross browser manner.

With underscore it is

```
function createOutput() {
    return _.reduce(arguments, function (memo, arr) {
        return _.map(memo, function(val, index) {
            return { x: val.x, y: val.y + arr[index].y };
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this fails the "efficient" test. It's l33t, but it's a *huge* number of function calls, and the first thing you do is create a copy of the "very large number of arrays". :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah that copy was unneccesary because `_` does that anyway. It's still `O(N)`. Yes there is overhead but it's terse and high level. I'm sure the Google closure compiler can factor away the inefficient bits.

Comment: @TJCrowder it actually wins the "efficient" test ;)